# How to display input box value from addImg.js (child component) to app.js (parent component) in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to display the input box value from `addImg.js` (child component) to `app.js` (parent component). How can I do that?

**app.js**

```
 function App() {
  var [add, setAdd] = useState(false)

  function click() {
    setAdd(true)
  }

  return (
    <div className="bigDiv">
      <button onClick={click}>click</button>
      <br /><br />
      {
        add && <Addimg />
      }           
     // I want to display text from input in Addimg.js here(in app.js)                
   </div>    
  )
}
```

**addimg.js**

```
    export default function addimg() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Please provide what you have done so far? Without the code it is not possible to understand your problem.

Comment: i added code ..

Comment: Tuzi, I have added the answer. Hopefully it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just pass a function `onInputChange` to `AddImg component`. And in `AddImg component` calling that `function` on `Input` change to pass `input` value so that it can be set in the parent component.

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  const [add, setAdd] = useState(false);
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('');

  function click() {
    setAdd(true)
  }

  return (
    <div className="bigDiv">
      <button onClick={click}>click</button>
      <br /><br />
      {
        add && 
          <>
            <Addimg onInputChange={(value) => setInputText(value)} /> 
            {inputText}
          </>
      }
      
    </div>
  )}
```

**AddImg.js**

```
export default function addimg({onInputChange}) {
      return (
        <div>
           <input type="text" onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e.target.value)} />
        </div>
       )
   }
```